# Cisco packet tracer no shut or no shutdown

Tags: cisco

I just want to whether their is any difference between the command no shut or no shutdown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference between those two commands in Cisco IOS. `no shut` is just a shortened form of `no shutdown`. If you were to type `no shut` at the CLI and press the TAB key you will see that it will complete the command as `no shutdown`.

Comment: Adam is correct.  Cisco lets you shorten most commands to as few unique characters as possible.  For instance, "int" is an appropriate shortcut for "interface", but "ip rout" does not work because it could mean either "ip route" or "ip routing".  As a general rule of thumb, as you're typing something in, if you use the ? key and only see one result, you don't need to type any more characters for that command.